# I can't click into at input field

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a big issue...
I got this site: sk.maze-it.dk

If you try to click on "BOOK MØDE" in the navbar and click on an available date (f.x 30) and then click on "Book møde"
Then there will come up 2 fields, one called "Navn" and another called email.

I can't type into them, and I'm really lost here.

FYI: I'm using Wordpress 4.9.6 w/ Cynic Theme & Booked Plugin, for the booking system.

I hope someone can help me out... 
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 2):

You have two other `<div>` containers which have the classes `modal fade`. Those appear to have a higher z-index than your modal window. If you delete them from the DOM, you can focus on the fields.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Chris for the reply! But I don't think I understand what you mean.. Can you please explain further?